# Mutating array extension vs inout function

Tags: swift

Given an array of `Color` objects, I want to be able to promote a certain color to the top of the array, based on a condition. Let's assume each `Color` has a boolean `isBright` property, and the test for promoting a color will be `$0.isBright`. I want to promote the first such color.

I would to provide a more general way to promote colors based on different tests. I have successfully accomplished this via two approaches, but I am not sure which is better. Please forgive me if I name or describe these techniques incorrectly.

## Option A - inout Function

```
private func promoteColor(from colors: inout [Color], where promote: ((Color) -> Bool)) {
    if let index = colors.index(where: promote) {
        let color = colors.remove(at: index)
        colors.insert(color, at: 0)
    }
}

// call site:
promoteColor(from: &colors, where: { $0.isBright })
```

## Option B - Mutating Array Extension

```
extension Array where Element: Color {
    mutating func promote(where promote: (Color) -> Bool) {
        if let index = index(where: promote) {
            let color = remove(at: index)
            insert(color, at: 0)
        }
    }
}

// call site:
colors.promote(where: { $0.isBright })
```

I prefer the readability of option B, but I'm not sure what else I should be considering when deciding which one to use. Are there any advantages or disadvantages of either?

## Edit

I suppose Option B can be generalized:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func promote(where promote: (Element) -> Bool) {
        if let index = index(where: promote) {
            let element = remove(at: index)
            insert(element, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, after your edit, I like the general extension on Array (but not the `where Element : Color` extension).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inout` should be avoided when possible especially when you have mutating funcs.

Your best easy option is probably this:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func promote(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) {
        if let index = index(where: predicate) {
            let element = remove(at: index)
            insert(element, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one other little update I thought of last night. If you are want more performance.

This second version will avoid the extra moving of elements after the promoted element. I've also tested it where the promoted element is the first element and it is safe with this logic.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func promote(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) {
        if let index = index(where: predicate) {
            withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (bufferPointer: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>) -> Void in
                let promotedElement = bufferPointer[index]
                for i in (0..<index).reversed() {
                    bufferPointer[i + 1] = bufferPointer[i]
                }
                bufferPointer[0] = promotedElement
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I caught the opportunity for the generic version just after posting, but didn't know about `swapAt`.

Comment: Ah, actually I don't want `swapAt` here since I don't want to demote the current first item, just bump it down a spot.

Comment: Ah in that case then removing it and inserting at the start is going to the best you can do. Sorry for missing that little detail.

Comment: I figured it was worth editing just so that the 'accepted' answer doesn't have that bug for anyone looking in the future.

Comment: I made one more set of changes to make it more performant and avoid a bunch of unneeded copies.